# Spark Dataframe to R dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, databricks, azure-databricks

I am trying to convert Spark Dataframe to R dataframe. Is there anyway to do it?

I tried to convert it to pandas dataframe first using .toPandas()
It is working, but again from Pandas to R dataframe using as.data.frame() is not working

Can someone help me with this please

Answer (score 1):

You can use [collect](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/R/collect.html) to accomplish this -

##### R DataFrame

```
%r

library(SparkR)

sparkR <- collect(sparkR_DF)
```